# double inexing an array without int

Tags: java, arrays, database, types, custom-data-type

I'm importing historical data for many stocks over certain dates into Java from CSV files.  My goal is to use a program in Java I built to trade (buy and sell) some of these tickers on certain dates.  The program is only configured to work with one ticker, but now I want expand it to work with thousands (over thousands of dates).

I have two tables, one containing the ticker and when to buy/sell, and the other (pictured below) with all the price and historical information.
Using the two, if, in table 1 I have an indication to by ticker **x** on **y** date, I want to be able to sell ticker x when the price decreases by, say, 80% from the purchase price.  In order to facilitate this kind of decision making, for each ticker I might trade, I have the historical data for about ten years.  I have tens of millions of rows in table two.

I'd like to be able to reference each of my columns (market cap, p/e ratio, beta...) using the ticker and date identifiers.  I'd like to manipulate my data in such a way as to (in Java) find the minimum and maximum of a p/e for a particular ticker over a certain date range.

I thought I should create a "numeric key" for each ticker and date combo.  It is each character in the ticker, converted to ASCII, concatenated, and added to the date.  I thought I could use each one of these as a unique identifier for indexing an array, but then realized I had no good way of figuring out when a tickers' data began and when it ended.

What data type would be better suited for this?

[image: DataTable]

Comment: You probably want a [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

Comment: @BasilBourque I have tens of millions of rows, but only 2500 tickers

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't it be better to use a `HashMap` and a key that combines ticker and date?

Something like:

```
public class TickerDate {

    private final String ticker;
    private final Date date;

    public TickerDate(String ticker, Date date) {
        this.ticker = ticker;
        this.date = date;
    }

    // .. getters

    // equals + hashcode
}
```

It would be definitely easier to understand in the code.

Other option is to use [`Table`](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#table) from Guava, you won't need to write the `TickerDate` class above.

Comment: That sounds very similar to an implementation I'm using in Access. Thank you!  (I'll give you the check mark after I implement it correctly.)

Comment: Yes, pretty much, but you don't need to have such big table, data will be in buckets.

Answer (score 0):

## Database

For a large volume of data, use a database. A good database like [H2 Database Engine](http://h2database.com/) is built to do exactly what you want (searching, sorting, aggregate calculations), and does so in an optimized manner.

H2 specifically is written in pure Java. It can be embedded within your Java app or used separately as a server.

If you have much memory on your deployment machines, and only need data temporarily, you can maximize performance by having H2 keep tables in memory rather than persisting to disk.

H2 can import directly from CSV files. See [this tutorial](http://h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#csv).

## Apache Commons CSV

The Apache Commons CSV is a handy library for importing/exporting to/from CSV and tab-delimited files.

I've enjoyed using it a few times successfully. Simplifies the chore of reading and parsing.

Comment: Would that mean I can I easily import a relational database from Microsoft Access?